# Xcode bugs with git?

Tags: git, github, xcode4

I'm trying to understand some of the current behavior of git in Xcode. When I push from within Xcode using Fine > Source Control > Push... two things happen that seem to be (possibly related) bugs:

(1) I get an error saying that authentication has failed and,

(2) I get a new remote repository added to my list of repositories in the Organizer (even if the same repository is already present there).

No approach to associating credentials with the repository seems to have an effect (and the duplicates added each time don't use any that I've entered anyway). But everything seems to actually function fine. Pushes (to GitHub) are successful.

Is this just a bug with Xcode? Is there some Xcode specific step to configuring git that I'm missing? I get the same behavior with nee projects where I apply source control on creation, and projects where I add source control after the fact.

I see that there have been issues and confusions with Xcode and git in the past, but I'm wondering what the status is with the current version of Xcode.

Any clarification is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I've got the duplicate Repository issue too. Also, when I commit, then try to push, it fails and I have to press commit again, then press cancel before the push works... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can connect with git by itself first.

Comment: Yes, no problems at all using Terminal.